# Find values that minimize function (by passing list as initial searching points)

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a cost function and I want to find which variables minimize it using the built-in method `FindMinimum`

My cost function is this (keep in mind that `y` is a list)

```
myCostFunction[y_, target_, expectedProbsTotal_] := 
 Module[{n, p, myCost, sumProbs, values, x},

  n = 3;
  myCost = 0;
  sumProbs = 0;

  p = Table[0, 3];

  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,

   p[[i]] = 1/(1 + Exp[-y[[i]]]);
   sumProbs += p[[i]];

   ]; (* for *)

  values = Table[0, 3];

  For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
   values[[i]] = p[[i]]
   ];


  For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
   x = values[[i]] - target[[i]];
   myCost += x*x;
   ];

  myCost = Sqrt[myCost/n] + Abs[sumProbs - expectedProbsTotal];
  myCost

  ]
```

What I am trying to do, using the syntax found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) is to find the values of list y that minimize my cost function, assuming that I have some initial values of

```
{0.6, -1.12, -1.5}
```

while `myTarget = {1.5, 3.5, 5};`

I tried this but it is not working

```
FindMinimum[
 myCostFunction[x, myTarget, 
  1], {{x[[1]], 0.6}, {x[[2]], -1.12}, {x[[3]], -1.5}}]
```

the error i get is:

> FindMinimum::vloc: The variable x[[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html)] cannot be localized so that it
>   can be assigned to numerical values.

I also tried the constraint `x[[1]]+x[[2]]+x[[3]]==1` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FindMinimum[myCostFunction[{x1, x2 , x3}, myTarget,1], {{x1, 0.6`}, {x2, -1.12`}, {x3, -1.5`}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
(*{3.39899, {x1 -> 0.288232, x2 -> -1.12, x3 -> -1.5}}*)
```

works.

If list argument `x=x1,x2,x3}` is an issue:

```
x = {x1, x2, x3}
FindMinimum[myCostFunction[x, myTarget, 1],MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {x, {0.6,-1.12, -1.5}}], Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
```

gives the same result.

Comment: I was looking for a syntax like this, excellent, thanks